# Angular JS and Springboot integration using rest api

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, angular-ui-router, client-server

I am trying to connect two different small applications. Client application is in Angular 5 and Server side is in Spring boot. Angular 5 application works fine on localhost:4200/register port and Spring boot (Server Side) works fine on port localhost:8080/api/demo.

For integration I have used added a proxy.conf.json file in Angular Application. I have updated package.json script also. Followed the instruction on the website: http://javasampleapproach.com/java-integration/integrate-angular-4-springboot-web-app-springtoolsuite#5_Import_Angular4_client_project_to_SpringToolSuite.

Both the projects are in same workspace.

Angular project files added for integration--->
proxy.conf.json :

```
{
    "api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false
    }
}
Package.json:
{
      "name": "my-new-project",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "license": "MIT",
      "scripts": {
      "ng": "ng",
      "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
      "build": "ng build",
      "test": "ng test",
      "lint": "ng lint",
      "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

SPRINGBOOT --->
    Rest API:
    package com.example.controller;

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class DemoController {

    //@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/api/demo")
    @RequestMapping("/api/demo")
    public String demo() {
        return "Hello Demo Application";
    }

}
```

So I want to access url like localhost:4200/api/demo   (localhost:4200 is angular and "api/demo" comes from Springboot )
Can someone please guide me here in the right direction. TIA

Comment: Rest API in Springboot Project:

Answer (score 0):

As said in docs either set server.port as system property using command line option to jvm --server.port=8090 or add application.properties in /src/main/resources/ with

server.port = 4200